# using 'foreach' in first() not working Laravel Eloquent

Tags: laravel, laravel-5.3

I'm trying to add an custom attribute unto the retrieved collection

```
$category = categories::where('cat_id',$id)->first();
foreach($category as $c):
    dd(var_dump($c->cat_id))
    $c->custom_attr = $c->cat_id;
endforeach;
```

but it throws me this error

> Trying to get property of non-object

not unless if I use 'get()' instead of 'first()' then it worked. If I do

```
$category = categories::where('cat_id',$id)->first();
foreach($category as $c):
    dd(var_dump($c))
endforeach;
```

it returns me

```
bool(true)
null
```

if I do

```
$category = categories::where('cat_id',$id)->first();
foreach($category as $c):
    dd(var_dump('xx'))
endforeach;
```

Sure the dump returns 'xx'. Any ideas, help please?

Answer (score 4):

You should use `get()` instead of `first()`.

`first()` gives you an object, `get()` will give you a collection of objects.

If you want to get properties, do not use `foreach()` or `for()`, just get properties like this:

```
$category->name;
```

Comment: but I'd rather use 'first()' because I'm expecting for only 1 item to be returned like using 'find($id)'

Comment: @CodeDemon yes, `first()` will give you one item. To access it's properties, use `$category->id`, `$category->name` etc.

Comment: then how can I modify the collection if I dont use foreach like add a custom attribute?

Comment: @CodeDemon if you want to add property to an object and save it to DB, do this `categories::where('cat_id', $id)->update(['custom_attr ' => 'cat_id']);`

Comment: @CodeDemon I can see you never upvote answers even if you say they were helpful. Please upvote helpful answers to show people you appreciate their time.